# How to write the x-path if the class names are available at run time(dynamically)

Tags: java, webdriver

```
<div id="gamesChooser">
            <div id="topMenu">
               <div id="blockView">
                <div class="roomButton room1 wide">
                <div class="roomButton room2 wide">
                <div class="roomButton room3 wide">
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

I have used the xpath like:

```
 //div[@id='gamesChooser']//div[contains(@class,'roomButton room1')]
```

But the  class `class="roomButton room wide` is dynamic, I never know if only `class=roomButton room3 wide` is available and the code fails

Comment: yes, I am looking for the x-path

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `nth-child()` of css

For third child it would be

```
#blockView>div:nth-child(3)
```

Comment: How can i write this without CSS?

Comment: Are you looking for `xpath`?